# Terraform - Enable Request Metrics on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Is it possible to enable [Request Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics.html) on an S3 bucket via Terraform, either using the `aws_s3_bucket` resource or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **aws_s3_bucket_metric** resource in Terraform. Passing the name attribute as **EntireBucket** enables request metrics for the bucket.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "example"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_metric" "example-entire-bucket" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket}"
  name   = "EntireBucket"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't enable metrics on the S3 bucket.

Comment: As @ydaetskcoR mentioned, I'm asking how to enable metrics on the bucket, not how monitor them or create alarms.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with the correct solution.

Comment: I could not enable request metric, it just enables storage metrics

Comment: This enables request and data transfer metrics for me, but it's totally not clear that it would given the options.

Comment: "Passing the name attribute as EntireBucket enables request metrics for the bucket."

In my experience, naming the resource "EntireBucket" was not necessary to enable request metrics for the bucket.  I used a different name and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Terraform resource for that: **aws_s3_bucket_metric**

You can emit "Request Metrics" for an entire bucket or create a filter to monitor a specific **folder** or file that has a specific **tag**.

Here is an example from Terraform docs:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "example"
 }

resource "aws_s3_bucket_metric" "example-entire-bucket" {
 bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
 name   = "EntireBucket"
}
```

**EntireBucket** is the name of a filter you will see in the AWS console - name it however you want (don't use spaces between words).

here is an example to monitor only the **documents/** folder:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
 bucket = "example"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_metric" "example-filtered" {
 bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
 name   = "ImportantBlueDocuments"

 filter {
  prefix = "documents/"
 }
}
```

Note the **prefix = "documents/"** - this is where you set a folder you want to monitor.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7LFX.png)

Read more on [Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_metric)